# Detect Passwordless SSH

Tags: ssh

I have a script that will run on host1 but will make some ssh calls to host2.  If host1->host2 passwordless ssh is not setup, the script will not work.  How do I detect whether passwordless ssh is setup or not?

If I do something like:

```
`ssh host2 ls`
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then 
    echo "Passwordless SSH works..."
else
    echo "Don't have passwordless SSH"
```

but passwordless ssh isn't there,  it hangs at the password prompt.

Basically, I want to call ssh but have the client die if the server requests a password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PasswordAuthentication option via the '-o' parameter to ssh. That should make the connection fail if it wants a password.

Comment: @Jonathan You can even disable PasswordAuthentication in ssh configuration file so that it will not ask for password.